# Getting flow to pick from a union of tuples

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a function that returns a union of tuples and it seems like flow is unable to pick one of these tuples no matter what I do.  Example ([try flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMRUA5ZAWwCMQYAKASgC54BtAURhhxgBp5VkECAF14AH1YChfAVRrCA3ACglYPAGcMrGr34VRAXkLEycuvWVKsieLR314AbyXx4GABZcA7vB3KAvioA9EF65PDq7jiCwPw4PtTwUGHUupTIWgCS8GBQqADkWmqoAG5Y6AiIEPHwODYeWOpKtLLMsqkWQA)):

```js
declare function genNumber(): [Error, null] | [null, number];

const [err, num] = genNumber();

if (err) {
  throw err;
}

// num should now be a number, but I can't convince flow of this
(num: number);
```

`num` on the last line should clearly be `number` but flow still thinks it's `null | number`.  I have a couple of workarounds, which is to flip the err check to `if (!num) {`, or to just have the generating function lie and change the return type to `[Error, ((null: any): number)] | [null, number]` but I honestly hate both of these.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is destructuring the result, as the analysis can't determine which of the return types applies.  A possible solution is covered in the docs, "[Disjoint unions with exact types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions-with-exact-types)", you're achieving something similar in your second example ([Try it here](https://flow.org/try/#0AQ4FwTwBwU2BlArgY2TAzu4BeYBvAH2HRTUwC5gAzAQwBt0YAaYGAJzYHs3KBRD7sAIBfAFChw0OADEaASzqI2cXIWKkM6cmDaJmwAHaIAtpSPGARuyFiJ40ABMYyOjWXVEB5GDmcDwAHMYAwA5Eys2AAoASkokVE0hYFkFJRgAbnsQLOBkP3QwYGUSOkLcINDw9hjMuwk5KmBIgEJixFKAOhIEzGj8HJAwAAsuAHcijHawDvYuNlrQW1AcgHoVwxNiIc52h0NOcatgGg3LdhzIts7zMyq2aMygA)).

```
type Success = {| success: false, error: Error |}
type Failure = {| success: true, num: number |}

declare function genNumber(): Success | Failure;

const result = genNumber();

if (!result.success) {
  throw result.error;
}

// num should now be a number
(result.num: number);
```

Update:
It seems that node style callbacks cannot be handled in flow at present ([Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2123)).

Here is how a node callback would be defined ([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0FAFwngDgpgBAwgewLYQDZRASwQOxgXhgAooAnUgLhgH4BRchUgGhlKgGcBXVEK6nTkgBGZAJQEAfDABuCTABMA3MGAAzTjgDGWXDCRgAYhs1F5uKFUQp0OnOIDewGDDM4oRAalQsAjKOUAvir6RlpEJOQsbFw84vhSjs6YqsRkpOIgABakCADuMGnKzk4wycTR3CDiRBU8VALCYkUwwAH+QA)):

```
type Completion = (err: ?Error, result: ?number) => void;

function myFunc(done: Completion) {
  done(null, 1);
}

myFunc((err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  if (result) (result: number);

});
```

And here is how your tuple could be defined ([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMRUA5ZAWwCMQYAKASgC54BtAfgFEYYcYAaeG1QVqMALoBuAFBSweAM4ZWNfvGHkx8ALyFiZKjQbSpWRPFor68AN5T48DAAseAd3grpAXxmnz6q7b2tOrM6qL0XkA)):

```
declare function genNumber(): [?Error, ?number];

const [err, num] = genNumber();

if (err) {
  throw err;
}

if (num) {
  (num: number);
}
```

Granted that this is still not as clean as you had hoped for.  I couldn't get Flow Try to pass a version of this with Promise as the input and return type, it doesn't seem to like the `await` keyword ([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwOYFMIA8AKgHwAUADgE7oC2qIuAXDAAo32PEkwA+MRAJQt2dBrgIBtAPwBRKjSoAaGNKIBdHgG8AUAEgquZAipYIuAO5sO4smUMh0AGwBuuFYYBWuKMkEwAXm0dGBg9PVFOXAA6YCcnMklqMUZ1QRCw8OjkAAt8e1wQBCdkQJ4HZzdEiGKnD0Li5EkABnU09NDwvWioYGQoHLJcMpgvH2RE9xga+PaAbn0AX0EFxZ0dKEwQUskYXAUVGtoYdUCYYAtgVFK8CDIARhX11DgYIYV-XJorfaoFnRebyO-jIRyYRwARvsVkA)).

```
async function gen<T>(promise: Promise<T> | T): Promise<[?Error, ?T]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Promise.all([promise])
            .then(result => resolve([null, result[0]]))
            .catch(e => reject([e, null]));
    });
}

const [ err, num ] = await gen(1);

if (err) throw err;

if (num) (num:number);
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that flow is through away the tuple information and just keeping `err = Error | null`, `num = null | number` which is a pain. 
 Keeping the data in an object or even array works, but I'm trying to find something cleaner as the actual use case is in a very generic utility function

Comment: I'm not sure a tuple is the clearest use in that case, I guess you're aiming for something more concise and that's why you went for destructuring.  If you could combine the `error` and `num` values into the same property, e.g. `result` you might get closer.

Comment: The actual function signature in my case is `function gen<T>(promise: Promise<T> | T): Promise<[Error, null] | [null, T]>`.  It's basically a try/catch wrapper that returns `[err, null]` or `[null, response]`.  Usage is then `const [err, whatever] = await gen(someFnThatReturnsAPromise())`.  Putting this in an object would tie the response and error together, which just seems weird.

Comment: Which begs the question, why not just use `Promise.then()` and `.catch()`?  Or why return a tuple, when a return type of `Error | number` would suffice?  I think if you edited your example to include the full context of what you want to achieve it might help.

Comment: Because I feel it's the best API :)  It's also habit as I'm trying to copy an API that exists in hack (exactly this) and node (to slightly less extent) which accepts callbacks in the form of `(err, resp) => void`.  I also have 5 other similar functions that are meant to handle slightly different intents which is why I'm not just using Promises.  But this is all off-topic.  I'm really just concerned with getting flow to behave with tuple unions, but that might be impossible for now.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more findings. Nothing seems perfect ;-)